# Spring Config Cloud and mutable properties

Tags: spring-cloud-config

Well, i have a project that some properties can be changed by user and others not. i.e:

```
- base_dir_pictures can be changed by user because they can choose another directory to save your images
- number_threads can't be changed by user.
```

So, with Spring Cloud Config all my properties will be saved in GIT, for "number_threads" property it's ok, but about "base_dir_pictures" should i use Spring Cloud COnfig ? What is the better approach to use it ?